# How to draw my graph with different label according to my membership vector?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I have a graph, and after some classification I extracted a membership vector like this:

```
vector membership is : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

which means its node's number `0:4` is in same class.
Now I need to draw a graph that nodes with same numbers should have same label. The number of labels here is 3.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Start by here : https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create a Graph, in which you have an attribute which contains the label for that node

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

member_labels = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
node_ids = list(range(len(member_labels)))

node_label_dict = dict(zip(node_ids, member_labels))

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(node_ids)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_label_dict, 'label')
```

So now your Graph has the following nodes and attributes

```
print(G.nodes(data=True))
#NodeDataView({0: {'label': 1}, 1: {'label': 1}, 2: {'label': 1}, 3: {'label': 1}, 4: {'label': 1}, 5: {'label': 2}, 6: {'label': 1}, 7: {'label': 2}, 8: {'label': 2}, 9: {'label': 2}, 10: {'label': 3}, 11: {'label': 3}, 12: {'label': 3}, 13: {'label': 3}})
```

Now you just need to draw the nodes and labels

```
pos=nx.nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
```

**Update**

```
# Fixed the variable name
labels = nx.nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos, labels=node_label_dict)
```

[image]